# Excel software conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

This rule is not working for me. Any clue why? G3 cell should get formatted with specified color but it's not getting formatted. Thank you in advance for your responses.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both cells are formatted properly as dates, edit the rule and remove the quotation marks.

The formula should be `=G3<H3`, not `="G3<H3"`.

Comment: Atzmon: the quotes are added by Excel - I do not have control over it.

Comment: Click "Edit Rule" and remove them. Is there any difference in behavior now? Can you make sure the cells are formatted as dates?